# setting HTML button image with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on my first website and I want to create an HTML button and put an image on it.

But the image has the wrong size and I am looking for a way to scale the image before putting it on the button. That's how I tried it:

```
function setImg(){
   var img = new Image(200,200);
   img.src = "imgs/youtubeImg.png";
   img.style.width = 100;
   img.style.height = 100;
   document.getElementById("youtubeButton").style.backgroundImage = img;
}
```

I don't know why it isn't working. I don't know if that is important, but this function is called after the button was created.
Hope you can help me, Thanks.

EDIT:
Method: appendChild:
[image]

Thats how it looks like with that function

[image]

But I want to let the img fit in this button:
[image]

But that only works if the image is the background image of the button.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this instead,

Using `appendChild()` to add a image.

```js
function setImg(e){
   e.classList.add("active")
   var img = new Image(200,200);
   img.src = "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1530103043960-ef38714abb15?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60";
   img.style.width = "180px";
   img.style.height = "70px";
   document.getElementById("youtubeButton").textContent= "";
   document.getElementById("youtubeButton").appendChild(img);

}
```

```css
button{
  padding:20px 30px;
}
button.active{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<button id="youtubeButton" onclick="setImg(this)">Youtube Button</button>
```

Comment: the first method didnt scale the image, but the second method just works perfectly. Thanks

Comment: actually there is one more problem. If I now try to set the borderRadius to something like 50% to get a circle it just stays on top and it doesnt change

Comment: I can't understand you words, are you add borderRadius to image ?

Comment: Please add screenshot here

Comment: I dont know how to put a screenshot in comments, so i am going to put it in the question

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post 
please refer this link.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>OP's solution moved from question to an answer:</sub>

> I found the solution. You can just set the background size, so it scales the image automatically.

Answer (score -2):

If you're setting the background image via css (as opposed to just appending it to the button which iou can also do) then you need to set the background-size attribute, look it up for details

Comment: Try to write answers that actually help people visiting this question in the future. *Look it up for details* does not make a good answer, and won't get you many upvotes. If a question can't be answered concisely, then *vote to close the question and don't post an answer*. At most, post what you wrote here as a comment, in such cases.

Comment: @martijn what are you talking about, the entire solution is background-size , most people know how to add css properties, if someone doesn't then they should look up how to use css, everything is answered here